# im making a mini antivirus that checks if in the files of a folder a specific text is in any of them

Tags: c, text, directory, readfile, antivirus

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 500

void myFgets(char* str, int n);

int binary_strstr(unsigned char* signutare, unsigned char* letters, size_t sign_size, size_t letter_size);

void normalScanner(char** filePaths);

void quickScanner(char** filePaths);

void freeargpointer(char** array);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int answer;
    char scanFolder[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char virusSign[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char** paths[2];

    printf("Welcome to my Virus Scan!\n\n");

    printf("Folder to scan: ");
    myFgets(scanFolder, sizeof(scanFolder));
    printf("\nVirus signature: ");
    myFgets(virusSign, sizeof(scanFolder));
    printf("\nPress 0 for a normal scan or any other key for a quick scan: ");
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    getchar();

    paths[0] = scanFolder;
    paths[1] = virusSign;

    printf("Scanning began...\nThis process may take several minutes...\n\n");

    if (answer != 0)
    {
        quickScanner(paths);
    }
    else
    {
        normalScanner(paths);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/*
Function will perform the fgets command and also remove the newline
that might be at the end of the string - a known issue with fgets.
input: the buffer to read into, the number of chars to read
*/
void myFgets(char* str, int n)
{
    fgets(str, n, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
}


//Normal Scan
void normalScanner(char** filePaths)
{
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* sd;
    FILE* fileRead;
    FILE* sign;
    FILE* logFile;
    char* filesChecked[LENGTH];
    char* sortedNames[LENGTH];
    int checkInfection[LENGTH];
    int i = 0;

    logFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\magshimim\\Desktop\\test\\log.txt", "w");

    dir = opendir(filePaths[0]);

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the directory!");
        return 1;
    }

    char signPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    snprintf(signPath, sizeof(signPath), "%s", filePaths[1]);

    sign = fopen(signPath, "rb");

    if (sign == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_END);
    int lenSign = ftell(sign);
    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* signutare = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (lenSign + 1));
    size_t size = fread(signutare, sizeof(char), lenSign, sign);
    fread(signutare, sizeof(char), lenSign, sign);

    printf("Scanning:\n");

    while ((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(sd->d_name, ".") && strcmp(sd->d_name, "..") && sd->d_type != 16384)
        {
            char filePath[MAX_PATH + 1], s, x;
            int characterCheck;
            int* position;
            snprintf(filePath, sizeof(filePath), "%s\\%s", filePaths[0], sd->d_name);

            fileRead = fopen(filePath, "rb");

            if (fileRead == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening the file!");
                return 1;
            }

            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
            int len = ftell(fileRead);
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);

            char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
            size_t sizeLetters = fread(letters, sizeof(char), len, fileRead);

            fread(letters, sizeof(char), len, fileRead);

            characterCheck = binary_strstr(signutare, letters, lenSign, len, &position);
            if (characterCheck != NULL)
            {
                filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                checkInfection[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                checkInfection[i] = 1;
                i++;
            }
            fclose(fileRead);
        }
    }
    fprintf(logFile, "Anti-virus began! Welcome!\n\nFolder to scan:\n%s\nVirus signature:\n%s\n\nScanning option:\nNormal Scan\n\nResults:\n", filePaths[0], filePaths[1]);

    //Sorting the names alphabiticly
    for (size_t f = 0; f < i; f++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            //filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] this grabs the first letter after the file path (first letter of the file name)
            if (filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] <= filesChecked[k][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1])
            {
                sortedNames[f] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(sortedNames[f], filesChecked[f]);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    0 --> Infected
    1 --> Clean
    */
    for (size_t x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        if (checkInfection[x] == 0)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 1)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "(ERROR READING DATA!)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
    }


    printf("Normal Scan Completed.\n");

    closedir(dir);
    fclose(sign);
    fclose(logFile);
}



//Quick Scan
void quickScanner(char** filePaths)
{
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* sd;
    FILE* fileRead;
    FILE* sign;
    FILE* logFile;
    char* filesChecked[LENGTH];
    char* sortedNames[LENGTH];
    int checkInfection[LENGTH];
    int lenFileO, positionChanger, i = 0;



    logFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\magshimim\\Desktop\\test\\log.txt", "w");

    dir = opendir(filePaths[0]);

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the directory!");
        return 1;
    }

    char signPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    snprintf(signPath, sizeof(signPath), "%s", filePaths[1]);

    sign = fopen(signPath, "rb");

    if (sign == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_END);
    int lenSign = ftell(sign);
    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* signutare = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (lenSign + 1));
    size_t size = fread(signutare, lenSign, sizeof(char), sign);
    fread(signutare, lenSign, sizeof(char), sign);

    printf("Scanning:\n");

    while ((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(sd->d_name, ".") && strcmp(sd->d_name, "..") && sd->d_type != 16384)
        {
            char filePath[MAX_PATH + 1], s, x;
            int characterCheck;
            int startPos = 0;
            int* position = &startPos;
            snprintf(filePath, sizeof(filePath), "%s\\%s", filePaths[0], sd->d_name);

            fileRead = fopen(filePath, "rb");

            if (fileRead == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening the file!");
                return 1;
            }

            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
            int len = ftell(fileRead);
            lenFileO = len;
            len = (len * 20) / 100;
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
            char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

            fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);

            characterCheck = binary_strstr(signutare, letters, lenSign, len, position);
            if (characterCheck == 1 && (*position <= len))
            {
                filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                checkInfection[i] = 0;
                i += 1;
            }
            else if (characterCheck == 0)
            {
                fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
                len = ftell(fileRead);
                lenFileO = len;
                len = (len * 20) / 100;
                fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
                len = lenFileO - len;
                char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

                fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);
                characterCheck = binary_strstr(signutare, letters, lenSign, len, position);
                if (characterCheck == 1 && (*position <= len))
                {
                    filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                    strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                    checkInfection[i] = 1;
                    i += 1;
                }
                else if (characterCheck == 0)
                {
                    fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
                    len = ftell(fileRead);
                    fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

                    fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);

                    characterCheck = binary_strstr(signutare, letters, lenSign, len, position);
                    if (characterCheck == 1)
                    {
                        filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                        strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                        checkInfection[i] = 2;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                        strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                        checkInfection[i] = 3;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    fclose(fileRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(logFile, "Anti-virus began! Welcome!\n\nFolder to scan:\n%s\nVirus signature:\n%s\n\nScanning option:\nQuick Scan\n\nResults:\n", filePaths[0], filePaths[1]);

    //Sorting the names alphabiticly
    for (size_t f = 0; f < i; f++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            //filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] this grabs the first letter after the file path (first letter of the file name)
            if (filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] <= filesChecked[k][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1])
            {
                sortedNames[f] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(sortedNames[f], filesChecked[f]);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    0 --> First 20%
    1 --> Last 20%
    2 --> Infected
    3 --> Clean
    */
    for (size_t x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        if (checkInfection[x] == 0)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Infected!  (first 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Infected! (first 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 1)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Infected!  (last 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Infected! (last 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 2)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s  Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 3)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s  Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "(ERROR READING DATA!)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
    }
    printf("Quick Scan Completed.\n");

    closedir(dir);
    fclose(sign);
    fclose(logFile);
}







int binary_strstr(unsigned char* signutare, unsigned char* letters, size_t sign_size, size_t letter_size, int* position)
{
    int x = 0;
    if (sign_size > letter_size) return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= letter_size - sign_size; i++)
    {
        int mismatch = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sign_size; j++)
        {
            if (letters[j + i] != signutare[j])
            {
                mismatch = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!mismatch) {
            // then we found the signature
            *position = x;
            return 1;
        }
        x++;
        // otherwise just go to the next iteration
    }
    *position = x;
    return 0;
}
```

in this function quick scanner im trying to loop through all files in a folder and check if a specific binary text is there.

if it's in the first 20% of the file then print infected(first 20%).

if it's in the last 20% of the file then print infected last 20%.

if not in the first 20% or last 20% of the file then check the whole file and print infected or clean.

the problem is I put in a file called "works.txt" the text i wanna search for is in the first 20% and its not printing first 20% and not working with last 20% too.

can someone help me i tried a lot of stuff debugged a lot of things not working
the problem is that the position gives u where the text started in the file but its giving the wrong position where the last/first 20%.

So i think the problem is with the position but not sure.

output:

```
Welcome to my Virus Scan!

Folder to scan: C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test

Virus signature: C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\f.txt

Press 0 for a normal scan or any other key for a quick scan: 1
Scanning began...
This process may take several minutes...

Scanning:
11   2) POS: 0
3    3) POS: 0
44805    3) POS: 44795
87341    3) POS: 87331
0    3) POS: 0
494    3) POS: 484
8997   2) POS: 14
46    3) POS: 36
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\f.txt - Infected!
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\hello.txt - Clean
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\kitten_frog.jpg - Clean
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\kitten_run.jpg - Clean
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\log.txt - Clean
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\q - Clean
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\works.txt - Infected!
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\yy.txt - Clean
Quick Scan Completed.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] you question, please, cleaning up your prose. It is hardly readable, orthography and punctuation make sense to communicate your thoughts clearly. Divide the text into decent paragraphs, show your effort to solve the issue, and ask a specific question.

Comment: i tried my best in asking i couldn't think of a better way also im not good at english it's the 3rd language that i speak

Comment: Even in your native language there are orthography and punctuation, I'm sure, and dividing into logical units like paragraphs. You can use any online translator to help you.

Comment: bro i really tried my best

Comment: OMG I FIXED IT :DDDD

Comment: Well, I assume you took the [tour] and read "[ask]". So you know what to do: Write an answer for future visitors. Later you can come back and mark it.

Comment: could you help me on freeing all the memory im getting lots of errors when trying to do so

Comment: That is another question, post it as such. PLEASE take the [tour] and read "[ask]"! Really, do it, you will not become happy here if you don't.

Comment: alright i'll make sure i do thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 500

void myFgets(char* str, int n);

int binary_strstr(unsigned char* signutare, unsigned char* letters, size_t sign_size, size_t letter_size);

void normalScanner(char** filePaths);

void quickScanner(char** filePaths);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int answer;
    char scanFolder[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char virusSign[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char** paths[2];

    printf("Welcome to my Virus Scan!\n\n");

    printf("Folder to scan: ");
    myFgets(scanFolder, sizeof(scanFolder));
    printf("\nVirus signature: ");
    myFgets(virusSign, sizeof(scanFolder));
    printf("\nPress 0 for a normal scan or any other key for a quick scan: ");
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    getchar();

    paths[0] = scanFolder;
    paths[1] = virusSign;

    printf("Scanning began...\nThis process may take several minutes...\n\n");

    if (answer != 0)
    {
        quickScanner(paths);
    }
    else
    {
        normalScanner(paths);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/*
Function will perform the fgets command and also remove the newline
that might be at the end of the string - a known issue with fgets.
input: the buffer to read into, the number of chars to read
*/
void myFgets(char* str, int n)
{
    fgets(str, n, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
}


/*
"Normal Scan"
Parameters:
filePaths --> array of char pointers (points to the file paths the user inputs)
return value:
1 --> on fail opening a file
*/
void normalScanner(char** filePaths)
{
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* sd;
    FILE* fileRead;
    FILE* sign;
    FILE* logFile;
    char* filesChecked[LENGTH];
    char* sortedNames[LENGTH];
    int checkInfection[LENGTH];
    int i = 0;

    logFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\magshimim\\Desktop\\test\\log.txt", "w");

    dir = opendir(filePaths[0]);

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the directory!");
        return 1;
    }

    char signPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    snprintf(signPath, sizeof(signPath), "%s", filePaths[1]);

    sign = fopen(signPath, "rb");

    if (sign == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_END);
    int lenSign = ftell(sign);
    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* signutare = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (lenSign + 1));
    size_t size = fread(signutare, sizeof(char), lenSign, sign);
    fread(signutare, sizeof(char), lenSign, sign);

    printf("Scanning:\n");

    while ((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(sd->d_name, ".") && strcmp(sd->d_name, "..") && sd->d_type != 16384)
        {
            char filePath[MAX_PATH + 1], s, x;
            int characterCheck;
            int* position;
            snprintf(filePath, sizeof(filePath), "%s\\%s", filePaths[0], sd->d_name);

            fileRead = fopen(filePath, "rb");

            if (fileRead == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening the file!");
                return 1;
            }

            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
            int len = ftell(fileRead);
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);

            char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
            size_t sizeLetters = fread(letters, sizeof(char), len, fileRead);

            fread(letters, sizeof(char), len, fileRead);

            characterCheck = binary_strstr(signutare, letters, lenSign, len, &position);
            if (characterCheck != NULL)
            {
                filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                checkInfection[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                checkInfection[i] = 1;
                i++;
            }
            fclose(fileRead);
        }
    }
    fprintf(logFile, "Anti-virus began! Welcome!\n\nFolder to scan:\n%s\nVirus signature:\n%s\n\nScanning option:\nNormal Scan\n\nResults:\n", filePaths[0], filePaths[1]);

    //Sorting the names alphabiticly
    for (size_t f = 0; f < i; f++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            //filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] this grabs the first letter after the file path (first letter of the file name)
            if (filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] <= filesChecked[k][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1])
            {
                sortedNames[f] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(sortedNames[f], filesChecked[f]);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    0 --> Infected
    1 --> Clean
    */
    for (size_t x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        if (checkInfection[x] == 0)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 1)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "(ERROR READING DATA!)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
    }


    printf("Normal Scan Completed.\n");

    closedir(dir);
    fclose(sign);
    fclose(logFile);
}



/*
"Quick Scan"
Parameters:
filePaths --> array of char pointers (points to the file paths the user inputs)
return value:
1 --> on fail opening a file
*/
void quickScanner(char** filePaths)
{
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* sd;
    FILE* fileRead;
    FILE* sign;
    FILE* logFile;
    char* filesChecked[LENGTH];
    char* sortedNames[LENGTH];
    char logFilePath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    char signPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    int checkInfection[LENGTH];
    int lenFileO, i = 0;

    snprintf(logFilePath, sizeof(logFilePath), "%s\\%s", filePaths[0], "log.txt");
    logFile = fopen(logFilePath, "w");

    dir = opendir(filePaths[0]);

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the directory!");
        return 1;
    }

    snprintf(signPath, sizeof(signPath), "%s", filePaths[1]);

    sign = fopen(signPath, "rb");

    if (sign == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_END);
    int lenSign = ftell(sign);
    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* signutare = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (lenSign + 1));
    size_t size = fread(signutare, lenSign, sizeof(char), sign);
    fread(signutare, lenSign, sizeof(char), sign);

    printf("Scanning:\n");

    while ((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        //Making sure we don't try to check . and .. or another folder (type 16384)
        if (strcmp(sd->d_name, ".") && strcmp(sd->d_name, "..") && sd->d_type != 16384)
        {
            char filePath[MAX_PATH + 1], s, x;
            int characterCheck = 0;
            int startPos = 0;
            int* position = &startPos;
            snprintf(filePath, sizeof(filePath), "%s\\%s", filePaths[0], sd->d_name);

            fileRead = fopen(filePath, "rb");

            if (fileRead == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening the file!");
                return 1;
            }

            //Getting the file length using fseek and reading data
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
            int len = ftell(fileRead);
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
            char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

            fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);

            characterCheck = binary_strstr(signutare, letters, lenSign, len, position);

            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
            len = ftell(fileRead);
            lenFileO = len;
            len = (len * 20) / 100;
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
            letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

            fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);

            if (characterCheck == 1 && (*position <= len))
            {
                filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                checkInfection[i] = 0;
                i += 1;
            }
            else if (characterCheck == 0 || (*position > len))
            {
                fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
                len = ftell(fileRead);
                lenFileO = len;
                len = (len * 20) / 100;
                fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
                len = lenFileO - len;
                char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

                fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);
                if (characterCheck == 1 && (*position >= len))
                {
                    filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                    strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                    checkInfection[i] = 1;
                    i += 1;
                }
                else if (characterCheck == 0 || (*position < len))
                {
                    fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
                    len = ftell(fileRead);
                    fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

                    fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);
                    if (characterCheck == 1)
                    {
                        filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                        strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                        checkInfection[i] = 2;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                        strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                        checkInfection[i] = 3;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    fclose(fileRead);
                    free(letters);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(logFile, "Anti-virus began! Welcome!\n\nFolder to scan:\n%s\nVirus signature:\n%s\n\nScanning option:\nQuick Scan\n\nResults:\n", filePaths[0], filePaths[1]);

    //Sorting the names alphabiticly
    for (size_t f = 0; f < i; f++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            //filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] this grabs the first letter after the file path (first letter of the file name)
            if (filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] <= filesChecked[k][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1])
            {
                sortedNames[f] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(sortedNames[f], filesChecked[f]);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    0 --> First 20%
    1 --> Last 20%
    2 --> Infected
    3 --> Clean
    */
    for (size_t x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        if (checkInfection[x] == 0)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Infected!  (first 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Infected! (first 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 1)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Infected!  (last 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Infected! (last 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 2)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s  Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 3)
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "%s  Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
            printf("%s - Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "(ERROR READING DATA!)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
    }
    printf("Quick Scan Completed.\n");

    closedir(dir);
    fclose(sign);
    fclose(logFile);
}






/*
"binary_strstr"
Parameters: 
signutar --> pointer to the signutare char array
letters --> pointer to the file data char array
sign_size --> size of the signutare array
letter_size --> size of the letters array
position --> is a pointer to get where the virus signutare in the file were scanning has started

return value:
0 --> if we didnt find the signutare in the file
1 --> if we found the signutare in the file
*/
int binary_strstr(unsigned char* signutare, unsigned char* letters, size_t sign_size, size_t letter_size, int* position)
{
    int x = 0;
    if (sign_size > letter_size) return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= letter_size - sign_size; i++)
    {
        int mismatch = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sign_size; j++)
        {
            if (letters[j + i] != signutare[j])
            {
                mismatch = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!mismatch) {
            // then we found the signature
            *position = x;
            return 1;
        }
        x++;
        // otherwise just go to the next iteration
    }
    *position = x;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem was that i called binary_strstr a lot of times for unnecessary reason.

The code now works perfectly the only needed thing is to free all of the memory used.

Im still working on freeing all the memory.